# MYSQL database Query-reg

Tags: mysql

```
select regno, SUM(IF(subjectcode='MA8402',mark,'A'))AS PQT,
SUM(IF(subjectcode='CS8491',mark,'A'))AS CA,
SUM(IF(subjectcode='CS8492',mark,'A'))AS DBMS,
SUM(IF(subjectcode='CS8451',mark,'A'))AS DAA,
SUM(IF(subjectcode='CS8493',mark,'A'))AS OS,
SUM(IF(subjectcode='CS8494',mark,'A'))AS SE FROM testmark where testid=1 
group by regno
```

few students ABSENT in particular test i have entered value 
   as 'A' but while displaying answer i got query result '0' for the row value 
   of 'A', How to print the A instead of '0'

EXAMPLE
   As per mysql value in testmark tables

```
 Regno  subjectcode  Mark
   101  MA8491        A
   101  CS8491        A
   101  CS8492        A
   101  CS8451        A
   101  CS8493        A
   101  CS8494        A
```

When Applied the above sql query i got answer like

```
 Regno  PQT CA  DBMS    OS  DAA SE
   101   0   0   0      0    0   0
```

Expected result is,

```
regno PQT CA DBMS DAA OS SE
  101  A   A   A   A   A  A
```

Comment: Please include sample data and your expected output.

Comment: What do you expect a sum of number A to be? My math only handles numbers 0-9

Answer (score 1):

You could use  ifnull  for assign 'A' to absent

```
select regno, 
MAX(ifnull(IF(subjectcode='MA8402',mark,'A'),'A')) AS PQT,
MAX(ifnull(IF(subjectcode='CS8491',mark,'A'),'A')) AS CA,
MAX(ifnull(IF(subjectcode='CS8492',mark,'A'),'A')) AS DBMS,
MAX(ifnull(IF(subjectcode='CS8451',mark,'A'),'A')) AS DAA,
MAX(ifnull(IF(subjectcode='CS8493',mark,'A'),'A')) AS OS,
MAX(ifnull(IF(subjectcode='CS8494',mark,'A'),'A')) AS SE 
FROM testmark 
where testid=1 
group by regno
```

(and you could use MAX instead of sum  .. sum for a string is not correct )

Comment: thanks for your response; I has executed the query as per your instruction but the output for the query is all the Column value as displayed like 'A';

Comment: In your sample you have  'A'  for all columns .. which is your eal expected  result ? update your question add  a proper data sample ... you actual result and the real expected  result  ..